# clear message php

Tags: php, session

Eu montei um CRUD e coloquei a mensagem "Registro atualizado com sucesso." para aparecer assim que for concluído o cadastro, mas não importa qual pagina eu vá, a mensagem continua, eu quero que assim que eu clique no botão `close` ele limpe a mensagem

```php
  <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['type']; ?> alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>    
    <?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?> 
  </div>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso o seu objetivo seja apresentar somente uma vez a mensagem (e não está incluído na pergunta, mas imagino que exista um `if(isset($_SESSION['message']))`, então basta fazer `unset($_SESSION['message']);` depois de apresentar a mensagem.

Ex:

```php
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
  <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['type']; ?> alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>    
    <?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?> 
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Uma outra opção seria usar query strings no lugar de `$_SESSION`. Assim o valor desaparece quando se carrega outra página (ou a mesma sem a query string).

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: @FelipeSilva neste caso não esqueça de aceitar e votar na resposta. tb é importante ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt - Versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?cb=1)